# How to make user's email unique in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am making a collection of user's data. This will be pretty basic consisting of user's email, user's password (hashed), and an array of strings.

```
{
    email: 'user@example.com',
    password: 'password hash',
    arr: []
}
```

I want to make sure that there can't be two inserts with the same `email`.
I read that the `_id` of mongoDB is unique by default, and it uses some special data structure for improved performance.

How can I make sure that the `email` remains unique, and if possible can I leverage the performance benefits provided by the `_id` field ?

Edit: I also want to make sure that there are no `null` values for `email` and that there are no documents which do not contain the `email` field.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it by creating a unique index for your email field.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/

Comment: I tried doing `db.collection.ensureIndex({email: 'text'}, {unique: true});`

But it is accepting multiple occurrences of `{email: null, password: 'passhash', arr: []}` as well as mutliple occurences of `{pass: 'passhash', arr: []}`

I want to make sure that there are no null values as well as missing fields. How can I make that happen ?

Comment: Creating a unique index and inserting a document without email you will achieve that. It's an ugly solution but unique indexes (without the sparse option) accept only one value for a field, so if you already inserted a document with {email: null} or {email: ""} (which are different values) all inserts without email will fail since they are considered as {email: null}. You also can contorl this cases in the application layer.

Comment: Also, you really should be controlling input in your application too. If you need an email address, it would be a lot faster to check for one in your application and catch it there if it isn't. Don't rely on the database to do it for you.

Comment: Not only should your application code ensure there's no null email values, it should also normalize them: Trim white spaces, convert everything to lower case, reject invalid address formats, etc. If you don't convert to lowercase, the index will regard "foo" and "Foo" as different addresses.

Comment: @LinJuuichi Instead of inserting a dummy document, it would make more sense to ensure an email index which is both [`unique`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/) and [`sparse`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/).

Comment: @Ishan You don't want to ensure a `text` index: that's for [text search](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/core/index-text/) which does language-based indexing (stemming to word roots, ignoring stopwords, etc).

Comment: @Stennie as I say, he wants to define an index with options unique and sparse. I'm just remarking that if he inserts a document with { email: null } or { email: "" } it will be inserted and indexed. Sparse only assures that documents without the value won't be indexed so he must ensure that email has a valid value in the application layer or insert the dummie document (which I don't like, but it's an option).

Answer (score 29):

Use [unique](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/) keyword, or simply make _id value to be email.

```
db.collection.createIndex( { email: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to use email: 1 when I know that I will be using strings not integers as email ?As it says here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/#db.collection.ensureIndex that 1 is used for ascending order.

I tried using `_id` but there is a problem that if no argument is passed for `_id` it just generates an id which is not what I want.

Comment: @Ishan The "1" in the index definition for `email` represents ascending order (vs "-1" for descending order). For an index on a single field like this, the order doesn't really matter as the same index can be used efficiently for ascending or descending search. Also, the index does not imply anything about the field type (string vs int) and does not have any relation to the `_id` field. What you really want to ensure a unique index without any empty values is: `db.collection.ensureIndex( { email: 1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true } )`.

Answer (score 16):

Mongodb `ensureIndex` has been [deprecated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/), use `createIndex` instead.

`db.collection.createIndex( { email: 1 }, { unique: true } )`

Comment: This seems more like a comment on [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28514316/2936460).

Comment: This answer makes sense because no one mentioned ensureIndex is deprecated..  everyone in the comment suggested to use  ensureIndex...  Thanks Mikko .